# Finding all cube roots with a number as a limit

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I want to find all of the cube roots that their cubes + their remainder add up to a number to user inputs. So for example, the query:

```
?- smallerCube(X,20).
```

Would give the result:

```
1 remainder 19
2 remainder 12
```

Since 1^3 = 1 (remainder 19), 2^3 = 8(remainder 12) and 3^3 = 27 which is bigger than the initial input of 20, and hence it's not being calculated here.

So far this is my code:

```
cubeLess(X,B,R) :- 
                   X =< B,
                   X1 is X*X*X,
                   R is B-X1.  

smallerCube(X,B) :- int(X),
                    X2 is X*X*X,
                    X2 =< B,
                    cubeLess(X2,B,R),
                    write(X), write(' rest '), writeln(R).

int(1).
int(N) :- int(N1), N is N1+1.
```

I use cubeLess to get the remainder, int to generate numbers from 1 onward.
However, when I run the following query:

```
?- smallerCube(X,130)
```

I get the following weird result:

```
1 rest 129
X = 1 
2 rest -382
X = 2 
3 rest -19553
X = 3 ;
```

Why did it work for X=1, but gave negative results for X=2,3?

Comment: Low-level arithmetic makes your program hard to reason about. I recommend you first switch to using CLP(FD) constraint to express relations over integers. See [tag:clpfd] for more information.

Comment: Well this is just an exercise for a course that i'm taking. CLP hasn't been covered and probably won't be at all so i rather not get into it..

Comment: You're calling `cubeLess` with `X2` instead of `X`...

Comment: right, that was the problem.. this is awkward haha
thank you!

Comment: Another question - using that code above, is it possible to calculate the sum of the remainders?

Comment: `findall(Rem, cubeless(X, B, Rem), Rems), sumlist(Rems, Sum)`?

Comment: could you please elaborate? i'm fairly new to prolog..

Comment: google findall/3  &&  sumlist/2

Answer (score 2):

**Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!**

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

No need to worry about using clpfd for the 1<sup>st</sup> time—you'll get the meaning in a moment for sure!

```
smallerCube_(X, Remainder, Maximum) :-
   X               #>= 0,
   Remainder       #>= 0,
   Remainder + X^3  #= Maximum.
```

First, the most general query of `smallerCube_/3`:

```
?- smallerCube_(X, Remainder, 20).
X in 1..2, _A in 1..8, Remainder in 12..19, X^3 #= _A, Remainder+_A #= 20.
```

One answer—*two* solutions: let's see them separated!

```
?- smallerCube_(X, Remainder, 20), indomain(X).
   X = 1, Remainder = 19                           % 20 #= 1^3 + 19
;  X = 2, Remainder = 12.                          % 20 #= 2^3 + 12
```

Here's the second query the OP wanted to run:

```
?- smallerCube_(X, Remainder, 130), indomain(X).
   X = 1, Remainder = 129                          % 130 #= 1^3 + 129
;  X = 2, Remainder = 122                          % 130 #= 2^3 + 122
;  X = 3, Remainder = 103                          % ...
;  X = 4, Remainder = 66                           % ...
;  X = 5, Remainder = 5.                           % 130 #= 5^3 + 5
```

**Done!** *So what's next?* Of course, that is up to you, so:

- Why not *re*-invest the time clpfd saved you?
- Why not read
  [this very compact CLP(FD) primer](http://metalevel.at/prolog/clpfd.html)
  as a jumpstart?