# Prolog - summing up predicate results

Tags: prolog, sum

Let's say i have the following predicate:

```
func1(X,B,R)
```

I provide it with a certain X and B and in return it gives me 5 different results for R.

EDIT:
The X and B do not specify a range. rather, X specify an integer (say 120) and B specifies all integers (starting from 1) whose cubic is less than X.
What func1 does is calculating R as the result the remainder.
In this case where X=120:

```
B = 1, R = 119 (120-1^3)
B = 2, R = 112 (120-2^3)
B = 3, R = 93 (120-3^3)
B = 4, R = 56 (120-4^3)
```

It would not calculate B=5 since 5^3 = 125 which is greater than 120, so it stops here.

How can i make a predicate such as:

```
func2(R,S)
```

That would accept all of the results given by R, sum them up and store them in S?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume, based upon your question, that results `R` are numbers. `findall(R, func1(X, B, R), L)` will collect all the results in the list, `L`, then `sumlist(L, Sum)` will sum all the numbers into `Sum`. In short, `findall(R, func1(X, B, R), L), sumlist(L, Sum).`

Comment: There's not enough information. How do you plan to provide *all of the results given by `R`*? Is `R` a given list of numbers? Or something else? The solution I provided would work *if* you are given a specific `X` and `B`. But you haven't made it clear what you are given.

Comment: All of the results given by R are provided by the predicate implemented (func1), don't worry about it. (it's not a list, just a bunch of numbers). The bottom line is how do i take those numbers and add them up in the func2 predicate?

Comment: Don't worry about it? It has a bearing on the answer. If it's not a list, what is it? Please give an example of a value for `R`.

Comment: I edited my original question and gave an example of expected values of R.

Comment: What values of `B` do you want to use when you generate your values of `R`? What I mean by that is, if you want to sum up all the values of `S` for a "bunch" of values of `R` where `S` values come from `func1(X, B, R)`, then the input range of `X` and `B` need to be known.

Comment: That depends on X. So for example, if X=120 (like in the example i provided in my original question), B will be equal to: 1,2,3,4 since those are the only numbers that when raised to the power of 3, will produce a result which is smaller or equal to X (120). I have another function that takes care of generating those numbers.

Comment: I understand now. `X` is really your variable. From there, you need to generate your values of `B`, then generate your values of `R`. Does each value of `B` have only one value of `R` from `func1`?

Comment: If the values of `B` really do depend upon `X` like that, then passing both into a predicate probably doesn't make sense. You should have `func1(X, R)` which, given `X`, will be true for all the values of `R` that make it so. Then use the `findall/3` predicate I showed in my first comment. Internal to `func1` you'd need to call another predicate which, given `X`, would be true for each value of `B` that makes it so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, since the values of `B` are totally derivable from the value of `X`, I wouldn't include both as arguments in `func1`. I'll introduce a predicate `func3/2` which is true if the second argument is derivable from the first (*i.e.*, `func3(X, B)` is true if `B` is derivable from `X`):

```
func1(X, R) :-
    func3(X, B),
    ...
```

What will happen if you query `func1(120, R)` is you'd get one or more results for `R`. Then you can use `findall/3` as I indicated in my comment:

```
func2(X, S) :-
    findall(R, func1(X, R), Rs),
    sumlist(Rs, S).
```

To define `func3/2` the cleanest approach would be to use CLP(FD):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

func3(X, B) :-
    B #>= 0,
    (X - B^3) #>= 0,
    label([B]).
```

Here's an example of what `func3` does:

```
?- func3(120, B).
B = 1 ;
B = 2 ;
B = 3 ;
B = 4.
```

---

A much less desirable way to do this if you can't use CLP(FD) would be to use `between` and define the upper limit of `B` to be the greatest integer not exceeding the cube root of `X`:

```
func3(X, B) :-
    Limit is floor(exp(log(X) / 3)),
    between(1, Limit, B).
```

Which yields the same result as above.

Comment: Thank you, but i think that what's stopping me from get it to work is the fact that i can't get func3 to return "false" at the end. So it gives me B=1; B=2; B=3; B=4; but then, when i press on the semi-colon, instead of giving "false", the cursor just goes down to a new empty line and it seems like the program is stuck.. why is that?

Comment: This is how i implemented it:

    int(1).
    int(N) :- int(N1), N is N1+1. 
    func3(N, B) :- int(X),
    X2 is X*X*X,
    X2 =< N,
    B is X.

Comment: (sorry i have no idea how to format it as code.. can't get it to work for some reason)

Comment: @Gambit2007 Why are you trying to generate integers that way? Is there a reason you can't use the CLP(FD) library? It looks like this was already suggested when you asked a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087702/prolog-finding-all-cube-roots-with-a-number-as-a-limit) but you did not respond to the comment. The reason your implementation fails is because it will infinitely keep backtracking, trying another integer in sequence, beyond the ones you care about. I added an alternative solution to my answer.

Comment: Alright i got it to work, many thanks for taking the time and helping me out! really appreciate it!